# How to use find command (with sudo) inside perl script?

Tags: bash, perl, find, filesystems

I have these files in pwd:

```
$pwd
/home/user/Desktop/perl
$ls
file.txt   foo.c   bar.c
```

Now, find command:

```
$sudo find / -type f -name foo.c
/home/user/Desktop/perl/foo.c
find: ‘/proc/1764/task/1764/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/proc/1764/net’: Invalid argument
/run/live/persistence/sda5/rw/home/user/Desktop/perl/foo.c
/usr/lib/live/mount/persistence/sda5/rw/home/user/Desktop/perl/foo.c
```

So the match is with the first path, what `find` found.
Now I would like to capture both files (`foo.c` and `bar.c`) in perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

@ar=("foo.c", "bar.c");
@ar2=`sudo find / -type f -name $_ | head -n1` for @ar;
print "$_\n" for @ar2
```

*output*:

```
find: ‘/proc/1764/task/1764/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/proc/1764/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/proc/29943’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/1764/task/1764/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/proc/1764/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/proc/30037’: No such file or directory
/home/user/Desktop/perl/bar.c
```

As you can see, I *can* use `sudo` inside of `` (backticks), but the result will not assign to the array properly (it gets only one of the files from the list, not both) even in list context. So how to properly find files in perl from `root` (and thus must with sudo privileges) via ``  in perl?

Comment: Assigning to an array empties it. Use `push @ar2, ... for @ar;`

Comment: For the third time, ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: I have warninga (as option in the interpreter, first line)

Comment: They're not quite equivalent, but I'm ok with that. Still missing the very important `use strict;`, though.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to not shell out in the first place. [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) works great for things like this.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Find::Rule;

my $search_dir = '/';
my @files = qw (
    foo.c
    bar.c
);
 
my @results = File::Find::Rule->file()
                            ->name(@files)
                            ->in($search_dir);

print "$_\n" for @results;
```

Results:

```
$ sudo perl find.pl
/root/foo.c
```

Note that if you're not using a system perl when using `sudo`, you might have to ensure your `sudoers` file has the correct perl path set. Here's an example of my system that is running 5.26.1 via `perlbrew` in my home directory:

```
Defaults secure_path="/home/steve/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.26.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

Essentially, I just added the perl bin path to the front of the existing `secure_path` entry along with a trailing colon (using `visudo`).